# Eclipse environment variables

Tags: java, environment-variables

I use Eclipse. I set for my project some environment variables. Can I get it from my java code with `System.getProperty("SOME_VAR")` ?

How can I get the environment variables from java code in Eclipse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**System.getProperty(String propertyName)** - this method is used for getting properties and not for the environment variables.

To get environment variable you can use **System.getenv(String envName)** method.

First link in google leads to this: [*Get Environment Variables in Java*](https://web.archive.org/web/20111105105906/http://blog.codebeach.com/2008/02/get-environment-variables-in-java.html)

Comment: I thought I was going crazy with getProperty not working, just was using the wrong method call. Thanks!!